# Grizzly supported war deploy failed in Glass fish

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4, grizzly

In my glass fish server 4.0 deploying of normal war files done well.
But while deploying Grizzly commet application war file deploying is failed.

Is their any another way to make glass fish to deploy the Grizzly enabled applications.

And error I got is [image: click here]

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish 4 embeds Grizzly 2 (2.3.1 to be more specific), where Comet classes have been repackaged. In Grizzly 2 Comet related classes are located in`org.glassfish.grizzly.comet.*`package instead of`com.sun.grizzly.comet.*`(for Grizzly 1.9.x).

According to your report, it looks like you have to change the package for `CometHandler`, please use`org.glassfish.grizzly.comet.CometHandler`.

Comment: This is one of those little gotchas I really would have loved had been easier to find. You saved my day... whatever remains of it.